# Google Sites; Editing

Tags: google, google-sites

I used a pre-made site but I cannot figure out how to edit it the way I want. I can't seem to delete pages that were pre-made, or edit the HTML.
Is that specific enough?

Comment: can you provide the link?

Comment: Or tell us how the pre-made site was created?  Are you using GoDaddy or other domain registrar's site building facility?

Comment: I am using google sites itself. it was one of the ones they had available. give me a minute and I will try to link you to the site

Comment: [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/underthecouchoddsandends/) is my site. I cannot figure out how to delete the pages such as amber crystals and that other mess. Nor can I figure out how to get rid of the subpages listing thing. I am using Google's editor program thing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Editing HTML with Google Sites

Google offers instructions to [edit pages and HTML.](https://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=153196) Here's a summary from that page:

1. Click the Edit Page button in the upper right hand corner of the screen. The edit toolbar will provide you with the tools necessary to edit your site.
2. Click the HTML button to edit the HTML on your site.

You won't be able to edit the full HTML of the page template, only the inner HTML relevant to the content on that page.

You can also insert [HTML boxes](https://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2500646) containing small snippets of HTML if you need to embed external content like a presentation on a page.

#### Deleting a page

Google's help pages have instructions to [delete a page.](https://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90551) A summary:

1. Go to the page you want to delete.
2. Click the More drop-down menu.
3. Select Delete page.
4. Confirm you want to delete the page by clicking Delete.